# Provisioning AWS EC2 instance using Vagrant and Puphpet

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, puphpet

I'm having trouble getting an AWS box up and running using Puphpet, Vagrant on Windows 7. The box gets created and I can SSH in to it (including vagrant SSH), but it seems there is a problem when Vagrant attempts to set up a synced folder (I have tried disabling synced_folder as per my config below, to no avail - same error).

Output from Vagrant:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...
==> default: Preparing SMB shared folders...
    default: You will be asked for the username and password to use for the SMB
    default: folders shortly. Please use the proper username/password of your
    default: Windows account.
    default:
    default: Username: Will
    default: Password (will be hidden):
==> default: Warning! The AWS provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
==> default: high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
==> default: will be silently ignored.
==> default: Launching an instance with the following settings...
==> default:  -- Type: t1.micro
==> default:  -- AMI: ami-a850c898
==> default:  -- Region: us-west-2
==> default:  -- Keypair: blerp
==> default:  -- Security Groups: ["blerp"]
==> default:  -- Block Device Mapping: []
==> default:  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false
==> default:  -- Monitoring: false
==> default:  -- EBS optimized: false
==> default:  -- Assigning a public IP address in a VPC: false
==> default: Waiting for instance to become "ready"...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Machine is booted and ready for use!
==> default: Mounting SMB shared folders...
We couldn't detect an IP address that was routable to this
machine from the guest machine! Please verify networking is properly
setup in the guest machine and that it is able to access this
host.

As another option, you can manually specify an IP for the machine
to mount from using the `smb_host` option to the synced folder.
```

config.yaml

```
---
vagrantfile-aws:
    vm:
        box: aws
        hostname: master
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.102
            forwarded_port: {  }
        provider:
            aws:
                access_key_id: AKIAIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXEA
                secret_access_key: F/Jbzz8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXI
                keypair_name: blerp
                ami: ami-a850c898
                region: us-west-2
                instance_type: t1.micro
                security_groups:
                    - blerp
                tags:
                    Source: Puphpet
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder: {  }
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: C:\keys\blerp.pem
        username: admin
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - htop
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups:
        - blerp
    users:
        - vagrant
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: 0
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        aigqp4eo8lau:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            directories:
                nxinqq2xcvog:
                    provider: directory
                    path: /var/www/awesome
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - all
                        - granted
                    custom_fragment: ''
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nzva8cncvz1v:
            proxy: ''
            server_name: pms.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/blerp
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '56'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: Europe/London
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.17.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        2zE2nPWS5zhS:
            version: ''
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions:
        ZWnnHGyd3QEG:
            version: ''
mysql:
    install: '1'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: secret
    adminer: 0
    databases:
        DVuYzweWmPBc:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: blerp
            host: localhost
            user: blerp
            password: secret
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    override_options: {  }
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in either Vagrant or vagrant-aws.

Syncing folders to remote hosts (like AWS, Digital Ocean, etc) should use rsync, not SMB!

Maybe you should ask those projects in their github repos - you're more likely to get an answer there.

Source: I created puphpet, I do not believe this is a puphpet issue.

Comment: Tested w/out Puphpet and you're absolutely right. Have opened vagrant-aws issue here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/365. Thanks Juan :)